Why am I getting an “Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.” when launching an .exe via Wine on macOS?
I'm trying to run this program on my machine (Apple Silicon) with the help of Wine.
I get this error stating:

Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
Input string was not in a correct format.


EDIT: Tried running the same executable on a VM, same error.


I am fairly sure .net framework allocations are incompatible with WINE. Worth pointing out that macOS does have support for .NET applications you would just have to recompile the application and target the platform. The error is due to your system not having.NET installed. There isn’t necessarily a solution to your WINE problem.

Is there any way I can address that? I tried running wine again after installing the official .NET Framework via Terminal, but this doesn't seem to address the issue.

My suggestion is to use a Windows VM. Otherwise, depending on the version of .net the application requires take the appropriate steps to install it: here

I'll try that and let you know. Thanks!

You don’t need to submit any additional comments just update your question, I won’t be notified of any comments, directed at me.

Wine isn't always reliable when it comes to running Windows apps on non-Windows machines. I agree with using a VM as an alternative. You could also try Turbo.NET.

@nollird: What information is displayed when you click on the <Details> button?

@Jackdaw - It’s a generic .NET exception that is throw when the .NET Framework doesn’t exist on the system

@Ramhound: Thanks. Sometime the track log is referencing to a specific software version and containing a detailed description of a problem.

It’s an unhandled exception. A stack trace won’t help in that case.  Besides I know the cause.

Have you tried using Mono, https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/wine-dotnet-mono.html, for .NET?

I tried it. I have trouble understanding if the program is fully compiled already or if it's a .NET issue (3.5 version). As you can see in the screenshots, my interface looks different to the one shown in the documentation (see links). Could you look that up?

Also tried recompiling the .csproj file, but get this error in the terminal:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.403/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1259,5): error MSB3644: the reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v3.5 cannot be found. To solve the problem, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) corresponding to this version of the framework, or retarget your application. You can download several types of .NET Framework Developer Pack from https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
